# C# to upload the file in project directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am using c# to save info in MS Access DB,And the form is using file upload control.And I could like to save the attached document of file control in specvific folder of the project.Can any one help me how can I do it.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the internet. [uploading a file](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FieUpload.SaveAs function is the one you looking for.

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
```

Also, check `Environment.SpecialFolder` library to find a suitable default folder as you like.

Comment: If you want to specify the running applications current directory, you would pass the following in as your `savePath`: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)`.